# How do I make a "branched" Conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I want the same data to be split in two "branches" to be processed separately, then "joined"...

```
                                +----------+
                +---------+  -->| doublber |---   +--------+
   +--------+   |         |--   +----------+   -->|        |   +------+
   | source |-->| splitter|                       | summer |-->| sink |
   +--------+   |         |--   +----------+   -->|        |   +------+
                +---------+  -->| delayer  |---   +--------+
                                +----------+
```

How should I do this?

My attempt:

```
import Data.Conduit
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL
-- import Data.Conduit.Internal (zipSources)
import Control.Arrow ((>>>))

source :: Source IO Int
source = do
    x <- liftIO $ getLine
    yield (read x)
    source

splitter :: Conduit Int IO (Int, Int)
splitter = CL.map $ \x -> (x,x)

doubler = CL.map (* 2)

delayer :: Conduit Int IO Int
delayer = do
    yield 0
    CL.map id

twoConduitBranches :: Monad m => Conduit a m b -> Conduit c m d -> Conduit (a,b) m (c,d)
twoConduitBranches q w = awaitForever $ \(x, y) -> do
    out1 <- undefined q x
    out2 <- undefined w y
    yield (out1, out2)


summer :: Conduit (Int,Int) IO Int
summer = CL.map $ \(x,y) -> x + y

sink :: Sink Int IO ()
sink = CL.mapM_ (show >>> putStrLn) 

-- combosrc = zipSources (source $= delayer) (source $= doubler)
main = source $= splitter $= twoConduitBranches doubler delayer $= summer $$ sink
```

What shall I write in place of the `undefined`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, but it's ugly, and hopefully the implementation will make it clear why it's ugly and not a built-in feature of conduit:

```
twoConduitBranches :: Monad m => Conduit a m c -> Conduit b m d -> Conduit (a,b) m (c,d)
twoConduitBranches q w = getZipConduit
      (ZipConduit (CL.map fst =$= q =$= CL.map Left)
    <* ZipConduit (CL.map snd =$= w =$= CL.map Right)) =$= collapse
  where
    collapse = do
        v1 <- await
        case v1 of
            Nothing -> return ()
            Just (Left _) -> error "out of sequence 1"
            Just (Right d) -> do
                v2 <- await
                case v2 of
                    Nothing -> error "mismatched count"
                    Just (Right _) -> error "out of sequence 2"
                    Just (Left c) -> do
                        yield (c, d)
                        collapse
```

(Note: I tweaked your type signature a bit, I assume this is the type signature you really wanted.)

Here's the approach: turn `q` into a `Conduit` that takes the first value from each incoming tuple, and then wrap its output with `Left`. Similarly, we take the second value from each incoming tuple and pass it to `w`, and then wrap the output with `Right`.

Now that these `Conduit`s have the same type (they take in the same input tuples, and generate the same Either values), we combine them using `ZipConduit`, which shares input amongst all components and coalesces the output into a single stream.

This stream is a stream of `Either c d`, not the desired `(c, d)`. To make this final conversion, we use `collapse`. It pops off a `Right` and `Left` value, and then puts them together into a single tuple which it yields.

This function assumes that the sequence of output values will *always* be one value from `w`, and then one from `q`. If anything else happens, it will throw an exception. The problem is: there's nothing in conduit to imply that they will in fact generate output at the same rate. In fact, conduit is specifically designed to *avoid* that assumption!

So, if you know that your two component conduits will always produce output at the same rate, this function will work. But this won't be true generally speaking.